# Escape double quote in velocity

Tags: velocity

I'm using velocity 1.7 and the template is below.

```
var jsCode = "${code}";
eval(jsCode);
```

if code is "var id = 123", then the actual js code is

```
var jsCode = "var id = 123";
eval(jsCode);
```

there is no problem.

However, if the code is "var name = "lucy"", then the actual js code is

```
var jsCode = "var name = "lucy"";
eval(jsCode);
```

obviously there is syntax error.

And if the code is var jsonStr = "{\"id\":1, \"name\":\"lucy\"}", the the problem is more serious.

The code is unknown, it can be anything.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: @user7294900 velocity version is 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity developed also [EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html) inside velocity-tools project which escape with different options

> Tool for working with escaping in Velocity templates. It provides methods to escape outputs for Velocity, Java, JavaScript, HTML, HTTP, XML and SQL

In your case it's javascript so use `$esc.javascript(` example:

> $javascript                  -> He didn't say, "Stop!"
>
> $esc.javascript($javascript) -> He didn\'t say, \"Stop!\"